# Creating Intention to Treat data in r: copy data from pre-test to post-test if missing post-test data

Tags: r, copy-paste

I am trying to create an 'intention to treat' dataset which copies a participant's pre-test data into their post-test data if they did not make it to the post-test session.

```
  This is a mock-up of the data set:
```

```
pretestURN <- c(100,101,102,103,104)
      pretest1 <- c(20,23,24,52, 65)
      pretest2 <- c(20,23,24,52, 65)
      posttestURN <- c(100,101,102,103,104)
      posttest1 <- c(20,23,24,52, 65)
      posttest2 <- c(20,23,24,52, 65)
      df <- data.frame(pretestURN,pretest1,pretest2,posttestURN,posttest1,posttest2)
      df[4,4:6] <- NA
      df
```

I want the code to perform something like this:

```
      df[4,4:6] <- df[4,1:3]
```

but automatically on the basis of missing post-test data. I think the easiest way to do this is by identifying post-test data on the posttestURN column. Here's my attempt so far:

```
           for(rowX in df){
        if(is.na(df[rowX,4])){
          df[rowX,4:6] <- df[rowX,1:3]
        }
           }
```

does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You're almost there - create an index of the missing values then assign from one subset to the other:  `idx <- is.na(df[,4:6]);
df[,4:6][idx] <- df[,1:3][idx]`

Comment: @H1 Thank you very much! been puzzling this out for ages. For anyone figuring out a similar issue, my final code is ```idx <- is.na(df$posttestURN) ; df[idx,4:6] <- df[idx,1:3]```